# Mobile app: Localfiles VS LocalDB?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing a mobile app using xamarin forms. I have to store few paragraphs to display on multiple pages.
I was wondering which is a better option LocalDb or files.

Comment: if it's just some static text I would use a local file or resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends how many paragraphs and how much time you want to spend.

The easy way is to use files. You just hardcode them and you read and edit their contents (page1p1, page1p2.. etc).

Local database is the better way to go because you can easily expand the number of pages and paragraphs and you it's easier to keep track of them. BUT there is more code to write... so it's not worth it for a small number of pages

Comment: Well in the app, there might be 5-6 pages each page has 4-5 sub categories. each sub category has 3-4 Q/A format. So, it can be total of 60 Q and A. So what would be your suggestion.

Comment: In this case a database, it's easier to manage. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html  You can create a table where you insert the questions and have a column  name textLocation (p1p1, p1p2,p,p2p1...)

Answer (score 1):

Local files is a good solution in this case.  You have a simple data structure and there is no reason to use additional memory and recourses when using a database.